# learnforge: View BIM 360 & Fusion models,"responded with a status of 500 (internal server error)" after 1 hour

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am folowing the learnforge tutorials (great resource, thank you)
the "View BIM 360 & Fusion models" part, everything works fine, but after 1 Hour i get:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) [http://localhost:3000/api/forge/oauth/token]"

It seems that its not getting a "RefreshToken" (just guessing)

I checked and double checked the settings and code.
In forgeviewer.js the GetForgeToken is using a fetch to get the required token but gets an error instead

```
function getForgeToken(callback) {
    fetch('/api/forge/oauth/token').then(function (res) {
        res.json().then(function (data) {
            callback(data.access_token, data.expires_in);
        })
    })
}
```

I would like the app to stay connected for longer than one hour.

any pointers?

Comment: we need to get down to the bottom of the server side error first - anything printed to the node console for the error? if not you can follow [here](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/debugging-node-js-with-google-chrome-4965b5f910f4) to step into node code and break on [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/blob/nodejs/routes/oauth.js#L33) to inspect the error

Comment: Bryan, its the .net framework tutorial i'm following. I don 't know how to log any error form the Oathcontroller.cs. Visual studio does not exept a breakpoint in it.

Comment: If VS doesn't break on exceptions for ASP.NET projects then see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @BryanHuang the error im getting is "Exception thrown: 'Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException' in mscorlib.dll".
I followed [this](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-viewhubs) tutorial and after 3600 sec i get this error. it seems i cannot get the right credentials again

Comment: Any stacktrace? At least exactly which line of line code was being called out? If somehow you couldn't get these i can give it a go later this week and see if there's a bug. Nonetheless you can always put your own code together to refresh tokens following [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/) and be sure to go for the three legged flow to get  refresh tokens.

Comment: I have made a wrong link in my previous comment.
So I tried the [.Net Framework] (https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/tree/net) Wich gave me the above error.
I'm affraid I cannot give more info than this (totally no programming background).

Today I tried the [.Net Core](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/tree/netcore) which worked perfect, gave me a new token after 1 hour (3600 sec).

Maybe if someone with more programming experience can look at the .net framework example.